# Conflict between xifthen and fixme?

Tags: pdftex, incompatibility, xifthen, fixme

Given the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[draft]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{fixme}

\newcommand\needscitation[1][]{%
  \fxwarning{citation needed%
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}%
    {}% if #1 is empty
    {: #1}% if #1 is not empty
  }
}

\begin{document}

Lorum Ipsum \needscitation
Lorum Ipsum \needscitation{me}

\end{document}
```

I get the following error when compiling with pdflatex, unless I comment out either line 7 & 11 or 8 - 10. Is there a way to resolve this apparent conflict?

```
compiling mwe.tex...
mwe.tex:17: Undefined control sequence \isempty.
mwe.tex:17: leading text: L
mwe.tex:17: Argument of \@tempc has an extra }.
mwe.tex:17: leading text: L
mwe.tex:17: Paragraph ended before \@tempc was complete.
mwe.tex:17: leading text: L
mwe.tex:17: Argument of \@tempc has an extra }.
mwe.tex:17: leading text: L
mwe.tex:17: Paragraph ended before \@tempc was complete.
mwe.tex:17: leading text: L
mwe.tex:17: Argument of \@tempc has an extra }.
mwe.tex:17: leading text: Lorum Ipsum \needscitation{
mwe.tex:17: Paragraph ended before \@tempc was complete.
mwe.tex:17: leading text: Lorum Ipsum \needscitation{
mwe.tex:17: Argument of \@tempc has an extra }.
mwe.tex:17: leading text: Lorum Ipsum \needscitation{
mwe.tex:17: Paragraph ended before \@tempc was complete.
mwe.tex:17: leading text: Lorum Ipsum \needscitation{
```

Comment: I am getting different errors. Please try to reduce your MWE to the minimum, get rid of unused options and use standard classes such as `article`. Makes it easier for us. Make sure, your MWE produces just the errors your describe.

Comment: You're right; I was compiling using rubber, I should have posted the output of a plain pdflatex call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the argument to `\fxwarning` passes through `\protected@edef` and `\ifthenelse` doesn't survive it.

You can do it at the expense of some code duplication, by having the `\ifthenelse` test outside `\fxwarning`

```
\documentclass[draft]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{fixme}

\newcommand\needscitation[1][]{%
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}
    {\fxwarning{citation needed}}%
    {\fxwarning{citation needed: #1}}%
}

\begin{document}

Lorum Ipsum \needscitation
Lorum Ipsum \needscitation[me]

\end{document}
```

or you can use a more robust approach. With `\NewDocumentCommand`, the argument specifier `o` is used to mark an optional argument; if present, the `\IfValueTF{#1}` conditional will follow the true branch. Here, since the false branch would be empty, I use `\IfValueT{#1}` that requires just one argument for the true text.

```
\documentclass[draft]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{fixme}

\NewDocumentCommand\needscitation{o}{%
  \fxwarning{citation needed\IfValueT{#1}{: #1}}%
}

\begin{document}

Lorum Ipsum \needscitation
Lorum Ipsum \needscitation[me]

\end{document}
```

Note that, in any case, the optional argument must go in square brackets.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Many things wrong here.

1. You are not using the `\needscitation` correctly in the second case. you need `[me]` not `{me}`
2. As LaRiFaRi I get a different error.

This test (using `etoolbox` instead`) works fine

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[draft]{fixme}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand\needscitation[1][]{%
  \fxwarning{citation needed%
    \ifblank{#1}{}{%
      : #1}%
  }
}

\begin{document}

Lorum Ipsum \needscitation
Lorum Ipsum \needscitation[me]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I wish I could mark to entries as the answer. I'm going with the one egreg only because it has more details on the cause, not because I think your answer is less valuable.